# How to trigger rest api calls on Database change without db triggers .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

I have an EXE Trying to call a rest api if a new record gets inserted/updated without using SQL trigger. Is there a way to do this in .net 4.7 similar to Azure function queue/storage triggers?

Comment: Some systems have push mechanism for changes you could subscribe to. But we don't now what you have.

Comment: I would like to stay away from messaging queue in .net 4.7 since it is no longer supported in place of Azure version. I also don't have Kafka.